# Word lover: Logophile. Grammar lover:?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m searching for a word to complete the analogy. While the word doesn’t have to be a “-phile” hat is the intended meaning. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Grammar-phile,  perhaps

Comment: Morphosyntactophile.

Comment: Hi Darci. We have certain requirements of questions. The first are our research standards: Did you check [a dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/logophile) to see if Logophile was a sufficient option, and if it is insufficient, did you check a thesaurus to see if there was anything that did? Why don't potential options work for you? Also, we require information regarding how you'll use the word, including an exemple of a context in which the word might be used, in order to help us choose the best option.

Comment: Using Greek, it'd be "grammatiquiphile," not to be confused with "grammaphile," a lover of letters, or a "grammataphile, a lover of spelling. 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This article](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/stop-calling-yourself-a-grammar-nazi) provides plenty of options: grammar lover, grammar peever, stickler, grammar grouch, grammando, grammar Nazi (with the intention of uprooting the last one). Only two of them are single words, though.

The author also provides some more options at the end of the article, however, most of them are about language purists; I'd say **grammando** is the most positively sounding of them all.